# How can I resume a persisted instance by a new version activity?

Tags: android-activity, workflow-foundation, persist

I have a Workflow Activity to handle task operations. The flow of the activity is "Create->Detach->Accept->Finish". A new workflow instance will be created for each new task. And the unfinished instances are persisted into database.
And after several days I change the activity, append a new step "Verify" at the last of the flow, so now the new flow is "Create->Detach->Accept->Finish->Verify".
I found that I can't resume the persisted instance by the new version activity. While I attempt to load the persisted instance, an exception thrown. How can i resume old instance by the new version activity? I want that the unfinished task can be handled by the new flow.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do about this in .NET 4.  Soon in .NET 4.5 there are new APIs that will allow you to update the persisted instance to prevent this.